# Can I implement this moving average with missing periods using ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have these columns:

- A person_id
- B date
- C cupcakes_eaten
- D date-35 (35 days prior)

There can be multiple rows with the same person_id and same date.

There can be days with zero rows for a particular person_id (so, missing periods).

I can use this this formula to calculate the 35-day moving average of cupcakes eaten:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,">="&D2, B:B, "<="&B2)/35
```

This works, and I can replicate this to all other rows.

Is there a more elegant way to do this using ArrayFormula so I don't have to replicate it to all the other rows?

Comment: Your question title refers to "missing periods" but there is no mention of "missing periods" in your question. Would you please clarify this (or edit the title).

Comment: Why not use a pivot table and filter out the blanks? Seems like the perfect use case for one.

Comment: I actually use a pivot table against the sheet which this sheet described in my question. here's the pivot table: `=QUERY('group-by-day'!A:E,"select B, sum(E) where B > date '2020-09-01' group by B pivot A", 1)`. What do you recommend for my sheet described in the question?

Answer (score 0):

First, delete any unneeded blank rows at the bottom of the sheet. Then try this in row `2` of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 1 / ( 35 /
    dsum( 
      if( 
        (A:A = transpose(A2:A)) 
        * 
        (row(A:A) <= transpose(row(A2:A))) 
        * 
        (B:B >= transpose(D2:D)), 
        C1:C, 
        iferror(1/0) 
      ), 
      sequence(rows(A2:A)), 
      if({1;1},) 
    ) 
  ) )
)
```